# What is the usual delay for a SEPA transaction?

Tags: money-transfer, online-banking, european-union, sepa

I wired some money from France to someone having an account in Germany, using a SEPA ([Single Euro Payments Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Euro_Payments_Area))

My bank acknowledged the transfer, and the person is telling me his didn't. He is telling me that these transactions usually take 2-3 days (he is also saying that there are holidays in Germany at the moment, which is true, and the transfer won't get acknowledged during that time)

Have you experienced such delay in SEPA transaction with similar conditions? 
Should I worry about being scammed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the SEPA Credit Transfers take 3 days excluding holidays. In future this would be reduced to 2 days and then eventually to same day. Your bank would have acknowledged sending out the transaction. It would go into the clearing house and then to the recipient's bank. Once the receiver's bank receives the funds, they would notify the receiver.